# how to build openssl to generate dylib

Tags: openssl

I have openssl source code with version 1.0.0a, I use ./config&make&make install, by default this command line will generate openssl binary for i386, also there is a libcrypto.a, this is an compress file generated by ar, nothing else, while I want to generate libcrypto.dylib. Can you give me some suggestion?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer, I just simple add shared option behind config, it will automatically generate dylib for me